# Wicket framework adoption

Tags: wicket

I am new to Wicket framework, I have seen many good reviews on this framework. 
I would like to know how is the adoption rate for Wicket compared to other frameworks (like GWT, JSF etc..).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a nice post: http://www.thebuzzmedia.com/which-is-the-hottest-java-web-framework-or-maybe-not-java/